# Subdomain works for non-SSL but not SSL

Tags: ssl, dns, cpanel, cloudflare, whm

I have a domain, `example.com`, on Cloudflare's nameservers. The domain is pointing at the IP address of my dedicated server, which is running CentOS/WHM/cPanel.  The site is accessible - all good.

I've setup an A record for `secure.example.com`, which also points at the same IP address as the root domain.

In cPanel on the server, I've created a subdomain for `secure.example.com`, which points to a subdirectory on the server, inside which I've placed a test HTML document.

Now, if I visit http://secure.example.com, I see the test HTML document.  All good.  However, if I visit https://secure.example.com (i.e. over SSL), I get redirected to https://secure.example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi, which is the page I would normally expect to see when a domain is pointed at the server but an account for that domain has not been setup on the server.

The `secure.example.com` A record is routed through Cloudflare's CDN, as I need to make use of their free SSL. The root domain is *not* routed through Cloudflare's CDN (i.e. it's DNS only) but I've tried it both ways and it has no effect on the problem.

So it seems that the server is recognising the non-SSL version of the subdomain, but not the SSL version.

My question is, why? Is this expected behaviour? If not, any idea how I can get it working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed SSL on your sub-domain that means there no SSL entry of you sub-domain in server httpd configuration file and that is the reason you are facing this issue with the SSL.

Comment: SSL is enabled for the subdomain on Cloudflare.  Surely I shouldn't need to install SSL on the server as well?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Cloudflare Shared SSL, you will need to configure it on your cloudflare dashboard. You should refer [CloudFlare support](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170566-Why-isn-t-SSL-working-for-my-site-)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I'm familiar with how Cloudflare works. As explained in my original question, I have enabled SSL for the subdomain on Cloudflare.